# ActiveRecord query help .count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a DB table users that has the following columns: id, clan_id, experience

I want to run a query using rails that returns the top 50 clans based on experience.  How would you do this query in rails?

Clan Table to User Table is a one to many relationship.  Thus a clan is composed of multiple users that have the same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clan.find(:all, :order => "experience DESC", :limit => 50)
```

Comment: clan table to user table is a one to many relationship.  It is possible for a clan to have more than one user.  I've updated the question to reflect this

Comment: This answer does exactly what you're looking for. You want 50 Clans sorted by `experience`. You should run the above query on the `Clan` model. The users table has nothing to do with your question whatsoever.

Comment: Can you post the code that returns that error? Where is the path_revenue value coming from?